# In the Eclipse WindowBuilder editor, the Design tab isn't showing anything

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, windowbuilder

When I create a jframe within a java project it shows me all the code in the *Source* part but when I go to *Design* it shows nothing? Would like some help on how to get the whole interface where you customise the GUI.
[image: Screenshot of design page]

[image: Screenshot of source page]

Comment: This is a good question (see answer below) and I hope it will not be closed like the [questions that asked it before](https://twitter.com/howlger/status/1309413178552582145).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a **known issue** of the Eclipse 2020-09 release which is **already fixed** (see [Eclipse bug 567071](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=567071#c7)).

Update to WindowBuilder 1.9.4 either [via the Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/windowbuilder) or via *Help > Install New Software...* and working with the update site [`http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/latest/`](http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/latest/).

Comment: You legend, appreciate it a lot