# In eclipse windows builder design view not showing anything

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windowsbuilder

What can I do design tab not showing anything?

I am used windows builder.

I am attached screenshot of that.

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64501472/2670892) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps as follows :

1.Open Eclipse.

2.Click on Help.

3.Then go in Eclipse Marketplace.

4.Search for Windowbuilder.

5.Click on Installed button in Windowbuilder 1.9.4.

6.Then click on Update.

7.and Proceed further steps.

*### Reference Link:*


https://youtu.be/LgOMN3US6Bk